# Number pattern prediction algorithm

Tags: algorithms, pattern-recognition

Since childhood we are all familiar with the task of predicting the next number in a sequence.
From something simple like, $2,4,6,...$ and $4,9,25,...$ to
something more complex like, $0,1,2^2,4^2+1,(4^2+2)^2,(4^2+2)^2+1,((4^2+2)^2+2)^2$ which would look like this if it was asked as a question $0,1,4,5,36,37,1444$.

There (probably) is an infinite number of different possible patterns.

My question is, does an algorithm exist that can predict any type of pattern? And considering that I think that the answer is no, my other question is, are there any algorithms that can predict any pattern to a certain level of complexity?

**EDIT**

@Thomas Andrews Thank you for pointing out the flaw with my question.
In light of that, I would like to change my question to this:

Is there an algorithm to determine a finite (or infinite) list of possible functions that match the given sequence?

Comment: No, and, in fact, there is no mathematically correct answer to "What is the next element in this sequence?" You might be interested in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences: https://oeis.org/

Comment: Would the question "what is the underlying function" be mathematically correct?

Comment: No, any number at all could possibly be the next number, so there is no "underlying function." I suppose if you picked a representation language - some programming language - and asked, "What is the shortest program that would output these numbers as the first $n$ numbers," then that would be well-defined, but would be highly dependent on the language.

Comment: in particular, every sequence can be continued by a polynomial, for example, which is nominally going to be less complicated for $4,9,25, $ than, say, "primes squared." We think of primes as "simple," but not so in most programming lanuages, compared to a quadratic polynomial

Comment: For example: $4,9,25,\dots$ can be written as $f(n)=4+5n+11\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\frac{11n^2-n+8}{2}$. Then $f(0)=4, f(1)=9, f(2)=25, f(3)=52.$

Comment: Pattern recognition is a useful skill to have as a mathematician and a scientist, but that's useful for being better at generating conjectures about how the series continues. For example, we know that the first perfect numbers are all even of the form $2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$ and we know that these are the only even perfect numbers, but we still have no idea if there are any odd perfect numbers. If someone started listing known perfect numbers, it could either be the sequence of even perfect numbers, or it could be all perfect numbers. Which is it? Those sequences might even be the same...

Comment: I can write an algorithm that will return an infinite number of different solutions, all polynomials. None of them will be helpful, however, if the underlying function is not a polynomial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pattern recognition is a useful skill in a mathematician, but it is not actually mathematically rigorous. There is no strictly correct answer, but, if you encountered a sequence in the wild, on some problem, the continuation would be merely a conjecture.

Consider: What is the maximum number of regions you get by drawing all the chords formed by $n$ points on a circle? That sequence starts:

$$1,2,4,8,16$$

You'd guess the next number is $32$, but it turns out, [the next number](https://oeis.org/A000127) is $31$.

That doesn't mean that recognizing patterns is not useful, but it is useful only in generating a conjecture about the sequence you are looking at, not an actually rigorous answer.

When mathematicians confuse conjecture and pattern-recognition, you end up making errors. I was reading Dickson's "History of the Theory of Numbers" a few years back, and was amused how often conjectures were stated as facts in ancient and medieval times. Did you know that for natural number $n$, there is exactly one perfect number with $n$ digits? It's not true, but was asserted as fact.

Modern mathematics is more careful. We might see that the first $n$ perfect numbers are all even, for some $n$, but we do not treat it as fact that all perfect numbers are even.

Every sequence of $n$ numbers can be written as a polynomial of degree $n-1$. Often, that isn't going to be the intuitive answer you wanted. For example, $4,9,25,\dots$ might be the squares of the primes, or it might be:

$$f(n)=\frac{11n^2-n+8}{2}$$

Which is it? It is neither, or it is both. The question does not have a single answer. Indeed, the next number could be made to be any integer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if you don't mind could you also answer the edited question. I hope that it is close enough to the original question.